# Search string not matching the input text properly

Tags: c, pattern-matching

I have a program which will match a search string (starts with one dot) in an input string correctly, but will not work for two or more dots.

main function:

```
int main()
{
    int position;
    char input[255], pattern[255];

    printf("Please enter a line of text of up to 255 characters:\n");
    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;

    printf("Please enter the search text of up to 255 characters:\n");
    fgets(pattern,sizeof(pattern),stdin);
    pattern[strcspn(pattern, "\n")] = 0;
    cmp(input, pattern);
    return 0;
}
```

cmp function:

```
char cmp(char input[],char pattern[])
{

    int i, pattern_position, input_position;


    for(int pattern_position = 0; pattern_position < strlen(pattern); pattern_position++) {

        if(pattern[pattern_position] == '.'){
            char letter_space_comma[54] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ',', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
            for (int  letter_space_comma_position= 0; letter_space_comma_position < 54; letter_space_comma_position++){
                pattern[pattern_position] = letter_space_comma[letter_space_comma_position];
                char *pos = strstr(input, pattern);
                if (pos) {
                    printf("Matches at position %ld.", pos-input);
                    goto end;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    char *pos = strstr(input, pattern);
    if (pos) {
        printf("Matches at position %ld.", pos-input);
    } else {
        printf("No match.");
    }

    end:
        return 0;
}
```

Input 1 (1 dot):

```
Please enter a line of text of up to 255 characters: The cat sat on the mat.
Please enter the search text of up to 255 characters: .at
```

Output 1(Correct):

```
Matches at position 4.
```

Input 2 (3 dots):

```
Please enter a line of text of up to 255 characters: The cat sat on the mat.
Please enter the search text of up to 255 characters: ...
```

My output 2:

```
No match.
```

Expected output 2:

```
Matches at position 0.
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn how to use a debugger. Using a debugger you can step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. This makes it easy to see when and where something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you should use a debugger and inspect the different values took by `pattern` string in `cmp` function:

```
for (int  letter_space_comma_position= 0; letter_space_comma_position < 54; letter_space_comma_position++){
    pattern[pattern_position] = letter_space_comma[letter_space_comma_position];

    /* HERE */ 

    char *pos = strstr(input, pattern);
```

When you have one "any char", you test well all the possibilities.

When you have two, for instance `..t`, you test `a.t`, `b.t` ... `z.t`, then `zat`, `zbt`... `zzt`.

---

One easy way to do what you want is to use recursivity:

1. prepare a new pattern to test for the first `'.'` character found
2. send this new pattern to depeer call.

But that suppose some changes in your `cmp` function:

- it *must* tell (by a returned value) if it found a match
- it must not print when no match is found (because it will be called a lot of time)
- it must not modify the `pattern` parameter passed: it must have its own copy.

Considering these elements, one implementation could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * cmp(char input[],char pattern[])
{
    int i, pattern_position, input_position;

    for(int pattern_position = 0; pattern_position < strlen(pattern); pattern_position++) {

        if(pattern[pattern_position] == '.'){

            /* make a local copy of pattern */
            char * pat = strdup(pattern);
            char * ret;

            char letter_space_comma[54] = {'A', 'B', 'C', ... 's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
            for (int  letter_space_comma_position= 0; letter_space_comma_position < 54; letter_space_comma_position++){
                pat[pattern_position] = letter_space_comma[letter_space_comma_position];


                ret = cmp(input, pat);
                if (ret)
                    /* if some match, do not test other possibilities:
                     * exist for loop, but not the function: you must free pat */
                    break;

            }
            /* free the local copy */
            free(pat);

            if (ret)
                /* match happened and mem freed: we can leave the function*/
                return ret;
        }
    }

    char *pos = strstr(input, pattern);
    if (pos) {
        printf("match at %ld\n", pos - input);
        return pos;
    }

    end:
        return 0;
}
```

I voluntary not changed your code too much, so you can still work on it and learn:

- remove the `printf` from `cmp` and display the final result from main ("match" / "no match")
- make `letter_space_comma` constant and static: their is not reason to set so many time.
- change the `cmp` prototype to prevent modifying `input` and `pattern` strings.
- simplify (remove useless variable, remarks that in `cmp` you can directly return the result of `strstr`....)

Comment: How do I make this work for case-insensitive input?  Because this works for case-senstive input, but not case-insensitive input.

Comment: @wei1999 Convert all your input to lower case with `tolower` for instance